# Отличие многопоточного и асинхронного программирования

Tags: c++, многопоточность, асинхронность

есть ли вообще существенные отличия между ними. Разве многопоточность не включает в себя асинхронность ?

Comment: К примеру, в Javascript очень развито асинхронное программирование, но многопоточности там вообще нет.

Comment: @ixSci [Web Workers](https://www.w3.org/TR/workers/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это вообще никак не связанные понятия. Асинхронность - это когда в обработке одновременно находится более одной задачи. А параллельность - это когда над имеющимися в обработке задачами трудится более одного потока. Код может быть синхронный / асинхронный, однопоточный / многопоточный в любых комбинациях:

- Синхронный однопоточный код - одну задачу обрабатывает один поток.
- Асинхронный однопоточный код - несколько задач обрабатывает один поток, причем потенциально переключаясь между ними.
- Синхронный многопоточный код - одну задачу обрабатывает несколько потоков.
- Асинхронный многопоточный код - несколько задач обрабатывает несколько потоков, причем потенциально переключаясь между ними.