# Асинхронное программирование на c++

Tags: c++, boost, асинхронность

Как работает/устроена асинхронная разработка на C++ и что для неё использовать?
Насколко я понимаю, если использовать те же callback'и в одном потоке, то это ничего не оптимизирует, потому что программа все равно будет останавливаться на время выполнения самого callback'а.

Как вариант, можно использовать **boost::fiber**, но и тут возникает вопрос, как правильно строить архитектуру программы, используя fiber?

Comment: [Отличие многопоточного и асинхронного программирования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/962041/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/962052) ну и fiber, ака легковесный поток, тут тоже сбоку

Comment: почему не оптимизирует? К примеру вам необходимо сделать запрос к серваку - это займет кое-какое время, которое можно провести с пользой и заняться чем-нибудь другим. Для этого запрос и чтение ответа делаются асинхроными. Тобишь запрос и чтение будут все в том же потоке, но между этими двумя операциями поток свободен и можно исполнять какие-либо другие операции вместо того, чтобы ожидать считывания

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, но ведь считывание тоже занимает процессорное время или в данном примере, идёт запрос, а чтение через handle вызывается той же системой при получении ответа?

Comment: @5133n не понял вопрос